# How to access one Vuex state from another in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have two Vuex stores inside the Nuxt `store` directory. I'm not able to access one store's states from another, even through `routeState`.

Store 1: `index.js`

```
export const state = () => ({
    token: false
})
export const getters = {}
export const mutations = {}
export const actions = {}
```

Store 2: `api.js`

```
export const state = () => ({
    apiBase: 'https://myurl.com/'
})
export const getters = {
    getAPI: (state, rootState) => {
        // Need the state token from index.js here
    },
}
export const mutations = {}
export const actions = {}
```

Here,

- `state` returns the state variables in `api.js`, that is `apiBase`
- `routeState` returns the getters in `api.js`
- `this` is undefined inside Vuex getters, it doesn't work

How do I access the state or getters from index.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rootState is exposed ad the third argument into a getter.

```
const getters = {
  getApi: (state, getters, rootState) => {
    // Access the state token from index.js
    rootState.token
 }}
```

Check this page for more details [Vuex Docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html)